# Confusion matrix exercise in Python using Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, loops, matrix

I am trying to build a confusion matrix (2,2) with True positives, False positives, True negatives, False negatives given two lists as input. First list contains the actual values and second list contains the predicted values with only 1s and 0s.

It looks like there is something missing in my for loop or if statements but I cannot figure out what...

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

y_true = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
y_pred = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

X = []
TP = float(0)
FP = float(0)
FN = float(0)
TN = float(0)

for x, y in zip(y_true, y_pred):
    if x == 1:
        if y == 1:
            TP += 1
        else:
            FN += 1

    elif x == 0:
        if y == 1:
            FP += 1
        else:
            TN += 1

X.append(TP)
X.append(FP)
X.append(FN)
X.append(TN)

Y = np.array(X)
Y = Y.reshape(2, 2)

print(Y)

Input:
1100
1000

Output:
[[0. 0.]
[0. 0.]]
```

Thanks in advance for your help! Also all comments on the content of my code and logic is more than welcome as I'm just starting to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, split() function has default value if you don't insert any character. The default value is space(' '). So. try not "1100", but "1 1 0 0". Then, You can get result that you want.

Comment: Thank you so much... it works as intended now. I feel dumb for not realizing this now lol. Have a good day!